# In a Google Group collaborative inbox, is it possible to set the default "reply-as" to reply on behalf of the group?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, collaboration

I have set up a collaborative inbox. This is to use as a customer support inbox. The "members" are all customer support personnel, but anyone can post to the inbox.

When members of the group reply to messages left there I always want to set the "By" field to be "Post on behalf of [group name]". Otherwise, the post comes from me, and the user's reply gets sent directly to me and isn't recorded in the group.

How can I set this by default? I've already sent one message while forgetting to set that. It will happen again, and again!

Or maybe I'm just using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has now been implemented in the new Google Groups:

[image: Send to group by default]

I tried it and it appeared to work.

Comment: In group settings you need to check "Advanced" in the top right in order to access this setting